# AR Core. Can i change share Camera on custom Camera with Gyro, accelerometer and magnitrometer?

Tags: java, android-camera, augmented-reality, android-sensors, arcore

I have a custom Camera with Gyro, accelerometer and magnetometer. Camera enabled with Galaxy S10 for Type-C USB v3.2 and I have a Java library for Android.

Can I add/change SharedCamera(standard) on my camera for plane tracking in **ARCore**? (Maybe make how in an emulator.)

If yes, where do I have to look?

Comment: Hi and welcome, you need to post here questions related directly to code problems, please reformulate your question or use other stack exchange site

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/